# Задача на списки не проходит скрытые проверки

Tags: python, циклы, list

Есть задача и вот моё решение, но оно не проходит скрытые проверки курса.

Подскажите что я делаю вообще не так и как это исправить?

Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).

Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.

Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка, разделёнными пробелом.

```
S = input()
s = S.split()
f = 0
l = 0
n = 0
k = 0
if len(s) == 0: # Если в списке нет элементов
    print(str(0))
if len(s) == 1: # Если в списке 1 элемент
    print(s[0])
elif len(s) == 2: # Если в списке 2 элемента
    n = int(s[1])*2
    k = int(s[0])*2
    print(n, k)
elif len(s) == 3: # Если в списке 3 элемента
    n = int(s[1]) + int(s[2])
    k = int(s[0]) + int(s[2])
    print(n, k, n)
else:                        # Для списков, в которых > 3 Элементов
    f = int(s[-1]) + int(s[1])    # Считает сумму соседей нулевого числа
    l = int(s[-2]) + int(s[0])    # Считает сумму соседей [-1] числа
    i = 0
    print(f, end =' ')
    for i in s:                    # Начинает считать сум. соседей остальных
        i = int(s[0]) + int(s[2])  # элементов, удаляя для этого нулевой элемент
        s.remove(s[0])
        print(i, end = ' ')
    print(l, end =' ')
```

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логику можно значительно упростить если воспользоваться оператором остатка от деления (`%`):

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(*[a[0] if len(a) == 1 
        else a[i-1]+a[(i+1) % len(a)] for i in range(len(a))])
```

PS этот вариант учитывает данное условие:

> Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers = input().split()
numbers = list(map(int, numbers))
new_numbers = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    x = numbers[i - 1]
    y = numbers[(i + 1) % len(numbers)]
    
    new_numbers.append(x + y)

if len(numbers) < 3:
    new_numbers = numbers
print(new_numbers)
```

Вариант, который предложил [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu):

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(*[a[i-1]+a[(i+1) % len(a)] for i in range(len(a))])
```

Comment: можно немного лаконичнее:`a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]; res = [a[i-1]+a[(i+1) % len(a)] for i in range(len(a))];` ;)

Comment: @MaxU ответы — в ответы

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, уже в ответе ;)

Comment: @MaxU где ??? ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, сначала [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185612/211923), но после того как Danis добавил это решение в свой ответ - в его ответе)